# belonging of one string to another string

Tags: c++, string, count, substring, function-definition

I have this function that checks if a string is a substring, is it possible for me to add a variable to it that will count to me how many times that subsequence appears in that sequence? or i need to create another function for that.

```
bool SearchString(string sir1, string sir2) {
    
    if (sir2.size() > sir1.size())
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < sir1.size(); i++) {
        int j = 0;
        if (sir1[i] == sir2[j]) {
            int k = i;
            while (sir1[i] == sir2[j] && j < sir2.size()) {
                j++;
                i++;
            }
            if (j == sir2.size())
                
                return true;
            else
                i = k;
            
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but at the expense of making it scan the entire string every time, whereas now it stops at the first occurrence.

Comment: Sure, add a counter, set it to zero, instead of the `return true;` increment the counter, and then return that value as the result. Done.

Answer (score 1):

For starters your function `SearchString` is too complicated and moreover can invoke undefined behavior in this loop

```
    while (sir1[i] == sir2[j] && j < sir2.size()) {
        j++;
        i++;
    }
```

if for example when the string `s2` contains an imbedded zero character '\0'.

Also the function parameters should have constant referenced types.

The function can be written much simpler.

As for your question then it will be better to write a separate function to count occurrences of a sub-string.

That is there is no great sense to count all occurrences of a sub-string in a string if you need only to know whether the sub-string is present in the string.

Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

bool SearchString( const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2 )
{
    return s1.find( s2 ) != std::string::npos;
}

size_t CountStringOccurrences( const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2 )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    for ( std::string::size_type pos = 0; 
          s1.find( s2, pos ) != std::string::npos;
          pos += s2.size() )
    {
        ++n;
    }

    return n;
}           

int main() 
{
    std::string s1( "123123123" );
    std::string s2( "123" );


    std::cout << std::boolalpha << SearchString( s1, s2 ) << '\n';
    std::cout << CountStringOccurrences( s1, s2 ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
true
3
```

Answer (score 1):

As "500 - Internal Server Error" said, you simply need to increment a counter where you return. With a little bit of refactoring it would look like this:

```
unsigned SearchString(const string& haystack, const string& needle) {
    if (needle.size() > haystack.size())
        return 0;
    unsigned count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < haystack.size(); ++i) {
        int j = 0;
        if (haystack[i] == needle[j]) {
            int k = i;
            while (k < haystack.size() && j < needle.size() && haystack[k] == needle[j]) {
                ++j;
                ++k;
            }
            if (j == needle.size())
                ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Note: it's important to check that you haven't reached the end of the haystack while searching for the needle. Consider haystack="ababa", needle="bac": trying to locate 'c' would read after the end of the haystack
It's also important to check reaching end before trying to dereference the next character:

```
while (sir1[i] == sir2[j] && j < sir2.size()) ...
```

would read **sir2[j]** before making sure **j** is not over the boundary.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like `std::search` as in

```
bool SearchString(const std::string& s0, const std::string& s1) {
    return std::search(s0.begin(), s0.end(), s1.begin(), s1.end()) != s0.end();
}
```

Counting would be a loop:

```
std::size_t count = 0;
for (auto it = std::search(s0.begin(), s0.end(), s1.begin(), s1.end());
     it != s0.end();
     it = std::search(it, s0.end(), s1.begin(), s1.end())) {
    ++count;
}
```

or perhaps clearer: pull out the duplication:

```
std::size_t count = 0;
auto search = [&](auto start) { return std::search(start, s0.end(), s1.begin(), s1.end()); };
for (auto it = search(s0.begin()); it != s0.end();
     it = search(it)) {
    ++count;
}
```

I bet there’s a way to do it with `std::ranges::count_if` but I don’t see it.